# Fuse IDE - camel routes design view blank

Tags: jbossfuse, fuseesb

I installed FUSE IDE and opened one of my workspace which has multiple projects containing camel routes.When i try to open this camel route xml files, i cannot see the layout of the route in Design mode.When project was developed the routes were defined in xml.Is there any way to view the routes in Design mode.?

Comment: Can you add details about which Fuse IDE version and Camel version that project is using?

Comment: But surely Fuse IDE can edit and show Camel routes. But it may require a newer Camel version than you may use.

Comment: @ClausIbsen if the project was developed without using Fuse IDE , and later we open the project in FuseIDE , can it show the design view? Also will the Custom components developed will be available in Fuse IDE? using Camel 2.10

Comment: Yes if the Camel routes are in xml, then Fuse IDE can show them in design mode. And yeah custom component is supported as well.

Comment: using Fuse IDE 2.10.I'll check once again if i was opening camel context where routes are not defined using xml , but instead java dsl and then imported.In this case i believe fuse ide won't be able to show the graphical view.

Answer (score 0):

That has happened to me a few times due to incorrect blueprint xml or some other parameter which makes the graphical layout completely dissappear or distort it. Basically save often, and check your blueprint for errors.